# JQuery resizable DIVs function not enabling drag behaviour (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to create two divs side by side with a draggable centre slider which expands/contracts the widths of the side by side divs.

I am using the jQuery Resizable plugin to achieve this. The slider bar shows but it will not drag left and right.

The jQuery plugin has been enqueued to the Wordpress API:

```
wp_register_script('csukcode_script_9', plugins_url('assets/js/jquery-resizable-master/src/jquery-resizable.js', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_script('csukcode_script_9');
```

How can I get the slider bar drag behaviour to correctly function? The jQuery has been added to a function that should fire on page load and correctly references the relevant div selectors.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
$(".pan1").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".rpanrResize",
   resizeHeight: false
});
})
```

```css
.outerSplitPane {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.pan1 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}   

.pan2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

.rpanrResize {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;  
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;  
}
```

```html
  <div class="outerSplitPane">
    <div class="pan1" id="pan1">
      <textarea id="yourcode" cols="40" rows="10">#Write your code here</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="rpanrResize" id="rpanrResize"></div>
    <div class="pan2" id="pan2">
      <pre id="output" class="output"></pre>
      <!-- If you want turtle graphics include a canvas -->
      <div id="mycanvas"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a live example of the site in development:

https://wordpress-935246-3248470.cloudwaysapps.com/testpage/

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix.

I didn't properly enqueue the jQuery library:

```
wp_register_script('csukcode_script_8', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('csukcode_script_8');
```

Sorry for wasting your time.